# how to fetch chat list in order with newest chat first using sqlite and android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, chat

> this is the function where i fetch my users according to the latest
>   text msg first but the query doesnt seem to work. can any one help me
>   out here.

```
    public HashMap<String, String> show_chat_list (String uid){

            HashMap<String, String> friend_list = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

> > **here is the query for fetching the name of the users engaged in a
> >     chat**

```
String selectQuery = "select * from friendlist where _id in (select com_id from chat_list order by _id desc)";

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // Move to first row
        boolean st = cursor.moveToFirst();


        if (st == true) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {


                    cfrname += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")) + ":";
                    friend_list.put("frname", cfrname);

                    cfruid += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")) + ":";
                    friend_list.put("fruid", cfruid);

                    badger += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("badger")) + ":";
                    friend_list.put("badger", badger);

                    cfrthumb += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("thumb")) + ":";
                    friend_list.put("frthumb", cfrthumb);


                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } else {

            friend_list.put("frname", "notdatainsql");
            friend_list.put("fruid", "notdatainsql");
            friend_list.put("frthumb", "notdatainsql");
            friend_list.put("badger", "notdatainsql");
        }


        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return friend_list;
    }
```

Comment: Your sql query should be able to return your data in the correct order

Comment: no its not its showing data in the order in which it is stored in the table friend_list @Nanoc

Comment: Then i think that you should modify your sql string to match your needs.

Comment: You are more than welcome for any suggestions. @Nanoc

Comment: Not aware of how your db looks like, cant give you a concrete sql query

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL query does not provide any order at all:

```
select * from friendlist where _id in (select com_id from chat_list order by _id desc)
```

The order here is not defined on your returned resultset, but rather in the sub-query which is only used to create the set of ID's that is later scanned to create the returned result set. The order of your returned result set is basically undefined.

You should be able to solve this using something like this:

```
select friendlist.*
  from friendlist
  join chatlist on friendlist._id=chatlist.com_id
  group by chatlist.com_id
  order by chatlist._id desc;
```

--

PS. Not really relevant to the question, but I am very curious on why you choose to represent each item by a HashMap of key-values instead of creating proper objects describing your data structure. Your current code seems really error prone, hard to debug and requires extensive use of string constants.

Answer (score -1):

**Use Comparator sort messages by date or any other field**
`Collections.sort(listMsg, new Comparator<MessageInfo>() {
                        public int compare(MessageInfo o1, MessageInfo o2) {
                            if (o1.Datetime == null || o2.Datetime == null)
                                return 0;
                            return o1.Datetime.compareTo(o2.Datetime);
                        }
                    });`

**In layout xml add following code:**

android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"

Comment: It seems like a really bad idea to have an SQL database, rely on items being sorted, but instead of using the power of SQL you are suggesting to fetch all items into memory in undefined order, and sort them in Java code. This should really be the last resort.

Comment: Besides, the op seems to want s list or people, sorted by order of most recent message by each user, not a list of messages. There are two tables involved.